# Access to parsleyField.$element in custom validator Parsley JS

Tags: field, parsley.js, customvalidator

Can anyone help me to reach parsleyField.$element in custom validator Parsley JS?

code:

```
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('customValidator', 
  function (value, requirement) {

// how to access here to parsleyField.$element ?? or how to access my custom data-attributes in field ?? 

  return false; //debug
}, 32)
.addMessage('ru', 'customValidator', 'message');
```

P.S.
Parsley JS Version 2.1.3

Answer (score 5):

Update to latest parsley, and use `function (value, requirement, parsleyField)`

Comment: Thanks Marc! This is the simpliest solution :) I hope this will help somebody else.

Comment: Sure. You should accept and upvote this answer then.